# Python creating sqlite3 database from excel ; however, it creates the database name as "database.xlsx.db

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

```
excel_file = self.filename
con = sqlite3.connect(excel_file + ".db")
wb = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name = [0])
for sheet in wb:
    wb[sheet].to_sql(sheet, con, index=False)
con.commit()
con.close()
```

Hi,
Above is a function which is called when I click on "Upload Roster" button (tk button). It updates the data into sqlite3 database perfectly ; however, the issue is that it creates the database files as "nameofdatabase.xlsl.db" instead of "nameofdatabase.db". Also, since there is one table in database, by default it's set the table name as '0'(Zero).
Any suggestion ?

Comment: please read "nameofdatabase.xlsl.db" as "nameofdatabase.xlsx.db"

Answer (score 0):

Use `os.path.splitext`:

```
import os
con = sqlite3.connect(os.path.splitext(excel_file)[0] + ".db")
```

Comment: thanks this works.......
Can you please help with something else ?
Above code always overwrite existing database, is there any method to append the database ?

Comment: secondly, the db above code creates makes the table and it's name is 0(Zero). Can we rename the table to something else ?

Comment: Have you read the documentation for `to_sql`? You'll want to pass something else than `sheet` as the first parameter, and use `if_exists='append'`. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html